# Manipulating the returned type of Entity Framework Model First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi I am using Entity Framework database first model.I am using my own stored procedures for accessing data and I seem to have some type result from entity framework.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [eConnect].[GetUserPersonalDetails]
@personId int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Persons.FirstName            as FirstName,
           Persons.MiddleName           as MiddleName, 
           Persons.LastName             as LastName,
           Persons.DateOfBirth          as DateOfBirth,
           Persons.CityOfBirth          as CityOfBirth,
           Persons.BSN                  as BSN,
           Persons.SecondaryEmail       as SecondaryEmail,
           Persons.HomePhone            as HomePhone,
           Persons.WorkPhone            as WorkPhone,
           Persons.MobilePhone          as MobilePhone,
           MaterialAddress.StreetName   as MaterialAddressStreetName,
           MaterialAddress.PostCode     as MaterialAddressPostCode,
           MaterialAddress.City         as MaterialAddressCity,
           MaterialAddressCountry.Name  as MaterialAddressCountry,
           HomeAddress.StreetName       as HomeAddressStreetName,
           HomeAddress.PostCode         as HomeAddressPostCode,
           HomeAddress.City             as HomeAddressCity,
           HomeAddressCountry.Name      as HomeAddressCountry,
           PostalAddress.StreetName     as PostalAddressStreetName,
           PostalAddress.PostCode       as PostalAddressPostCode,
           PostalAddress.City           as PostalAddressCity,
           PostalAddressCountry.Name    as PostalAddressCountry,
           Company.Name                 as CompanyName,
           Company.Phone                as CompanyPhone,
           Avatar.FileName              as FileName,
           Avatar.RealName              as RealName
    FROM Sync_Persons as Persons
    LEFT JOIN Sync_Addresses as MaterialAddress ON Persons.MaterialAddressID = MaterialAddress.AddressID 
                                                AND MaterialAddress.Deletion_Date IS NULL   
    LEFT JOIN Countries as MaterialAddressCountry ON MaterialAddress.CountryID = MaterialAddressCountry.CountryID 
                                                  AND MaterialAddressCountry.Deletion_Date IS NULL  
    LEFT JOIN Sync_Addresses as HomeAddress ON Persons.HomeAddressID = HomeAddress.AddressID 
                                            AND HomeAddress.Deletion_Date IS NULL
    LEFT JOIN Countries as HomeAddressCountry ON HomeAddress.CountryID = HomeAddressCountry.CountryID 
                                              AND HomeAddressCountry.Deletion_Date IS NULL
    LEFT JOIN Sync_Addresses as PostalAddress ON Persons.PostalAddressId = PostalAddress.AddressID 
                                              AND PostalAddress.Deletion_Date IS NULL
    LEFT JOIN Countries as PostalAddressCountry ON PostalAddress.CountryID = PostalAddressCountry.CountryID 
                                                AND PostalAddressCountry.Deletion_Date IS NULL
    LEFT JOIN Sync_Companies as Company ON Persons.CompanyID = Company.CompanyID 
                                        AND Company.Deletion_Date IS NULL
    LEFT JOIN Documents as Avatar ON Persons.AvatarPictureDocumentID = Avatar.DocumentID 
                                  AND Avatar.Deletion_Date IS NULL
    WHERE Persons.PersonID = @personId
```

And after adding the updating the model and calling this procedure in code like this:

```
 m_DataContext.GetUserPersonalDetails(personId);
```

I get back this:

```
ObjectResult<GetUserPersonalDetails_Result>
```

In my case this stored procedure will always return one value because personId will be my table identifier.

I expected to get back an object of type GetUserPersonalDetails_Result.

How can I tell Entity Framework to return GetUserPersonalDetails_Result or how can I convert ObjectResult to GetUserPersonalDetails_Result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObjectResult` is just a [collection of results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739113.aspx). You can use `First()`, `Single()`, or anything you normally would on a collection to get the result you desire. It becomes a collection because Entity Framework can never guarantee that your store procedure will **always** return one result.